# How to pick specific word in the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data which I have splitted using split function.
Data looks like this

Sample Data :

[image]

Here I want to pick the words 3 rows (Emp_name ,as ,EmployeeName)and( Dept_name, As, DepartmentName) and make it as single row.

**ID   Str_Name**

```
1  Emp_Name As EmployeeName

2  Dept_name As DepartmentName

3  Emp_Id As Employee Status
```

I'm unable to proceed on this how  I can achieve this . Can you suggest on this.

Comment: What logic do you want to do to select those rows?  Anywhere the word `AS` appears take the word before and the word after, or something else?

Comment: yes @JohnLBevan actually this is the requirement . But actually I have used in split function in my requirement but need of those alias columns in code. So that's the reason I have asked question

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. But if you really want to continue this path just use a couple of replaces. One to replace " as " with something like [[[as]]], do your split, then do another replace to put back " as ".

Comment: with in the split function itself . how can I handle this requirement

Comment: How would we know? What split function are you using?

Comment: ex : Select emp_name from employee it got splitted into 4 rows...@SeanLange regular split function

Comment: Putting your comments together it is starting to sound like you want a TSQL parser, e.g. [`TSqlParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sqlserver-2016).

Comment: What is "regular split function"? Is this STRING_SPLIT or a user defined function?

Comment: @SeanLange yes it is kind of user defined function it splits a column sentence into multiple rows

Comment: And you are asking how you can do something with the function itself but haven't posted the function.

Answer (score 3):

Since the ID is consecutive, you just need to find those rows with value `AS` and the row before (ID-1) and after (ID+1) and concatenate the results.  [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c3bf273186e2eb6d9317f6b3d17d84c7).

```
select b.Id, a.Name + ' ' + b.Name + ' ' + c.Name StrName 
from SampleData b
inner join SampleData a on a.Id = b.id - 1
inner join SampleData c on c.Id = b.id + 1
where b.Name = 'AS'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer can you please suggest me how to handle when there is a Case statement

Comment: @mohan111 What's your actual requirement?  i.e. If you can describe what you're end goal is we can provide a good solution; otherwise we'll only be able to give you piecemeal bits / which may add up to something unsupportable when there's a much better solution available were we to understand the holistic view.

Comment: @Sami yes exactly more over it is a sample data If any misses are there try to ignore it

Comment: @JohnLBevan what ever the answer you gave it is correct but when coming to case condition it is not giving table name and alias name

Comment: How should the logic behave if we have `select Emp_SalaryInCents/100 as EmployeeSalaryInDollars`, or if we have `select Emp_CurrencySymbol +  cast(Emp_Salary as nvarchar(9)) as DisplayableSalary`?  What if we had `select Emp_Name EmployeeName` (i.e. without the optional `AS`)? Does our solution need to handle all these myriad possibities?  What's this ultimately achieving?

Answer (score 0):

`Select STRING_AGG(Name,'') from Table where Id%2=0 and Id<11) ;` 
Generally We could have done by making use of some agg functions like SUM etc as it is multiple rows to one row aggregation But It seems not possible via these I tried it with group_concat

Comment: This is clearly tagged with sql server. GROUP_CONCAT does not exist with sql server, that is a mysql function.

Comment: Perhaps I got what I was looking for lookalike of list_aggr/group_concat like functions for aggregation of multiple into one is STRING_AGG introduced in 2017 thankfully

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is how to delimit one field definition from another, and that is the comma that's doing it. So assigning a group number to all STRINGs beginning from the smallest to the largest ID and incrementing the group number only when a comma is found will give which STRINGs should be concatenated together.
Sample implementation involves the window function SUM (the OVER clause makes it a window function), and the FOR XML PATH('') for concatenation:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,STRING VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT @test
VALUES
    (1, 'SELECT')
    ,(2, 'Emp_id')
    ,(3, ',')
    ,(4, 'Emp_Name')
    ,(5, 'AS')
    ,(6, 'EmployeeName')
    ,(7, ',')
    ,(8, 'Dept_Name')
    ,(9, 'AS')
    ,(10, 'DepartmentName')
    ,(11, ',')
    ,(12, 'CASE')
    ,(13, 'WHEN')
    ,(14, 'Emp_Status = ''Y''')
    ,(15, 'THEN')
    ,(16, '1')
    ,(17, 'ELSE')
    ,(18, '0')
    ,(19, 'END')
    ,(20, 'AS')
    ,(21, 'EmployeeStatus')

-- Only to show progress:
SELECT * FROM @test ORDER BY ID



SELECT *, SUM (CASE WHEN STRING = ',' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as GroupID
INTO #test
FROM @test

-- Only to show progress:
SELECT * FROM #test ORDER BY ID



SELECT
    GroupID
    ,(SELECT GroupElements.STRING + ' '
      FROM #test as GroupElements
      WHERE GroupElements.GroupID = Groups.GroupID and GroupElements.STRING != 'SELECT'
      FOR XML PATH('')) as STRING
FROM (SELECT distinct GroupID FROM #test) as Groups
ORDER BY GroupID
```

Needs to be adjusted if you don't want the group numbering from zero, don't want the comma itself in the result, need the word SELECT, or the fields that contain the comma or the SELECT have other characters as well - test your cases